# App crashing when trying to share a view

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

My app is crashing (only for some users) when they click on Share. This is the code:

```
@IBAction func btnShare(sender: AnyObject) {
    let message = "Some message"
    let shareUrl = "mydomain://someurl/\(someid)"

    if let url = NSURL(string: shareUrl) {
        let objectsToShare = [message, url]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the crash report:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184a32014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184af9460 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1849a63f4 abort + 140
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100d83928 swift::fatalError(char const*, ...) + 50
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100d6c0f0 swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(void const*, char const*, void const*, char const*, char const*) + 70
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100d6c180 swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(swift::Metadata const*, swift::Metadata const*, char const*) + 142
6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100d92460 swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 68
7  Wize                           0x100117198 specialized MyViewController.btnShare(AnyObject) -> () (MyViewController.swift:363)
8  Wize                           0x1001132b0 @objc MyViewController.btnShare(AnyObject) -> () (MyViewController.swift)
9  UIKit                          0x18b8e27b0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
10 UIKit                          0x18ba565ec -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 168
11 UIKit                          0x18b8e27b0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
12 UIKit                          0x18b8e2730 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
13 UIKit                          0x18b8ccbe4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452
14 UIKit                          0x18b8ccd4c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 812
15 UIKit                          0x18b8e201c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
16 UIKit                          0x18b8e1b44 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2484
17 UIKit                          0x18b8dcd8c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2988
18 UIKit                          0x18b8ad858 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
19 UIKit                          0x18c09acb8 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
20 UIKit                          0x18c094720 __handleEventQueue + 784
21 CoreFoundation                 0x185a12278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
22 CoreFoundation                 0x185a11bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
23 CoreFoundation                 0x185a0f7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18593e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
25 GraphicsServices               0x1873c1198 GSEventRunModal + 180
26 UIKit                          0x18b918628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
27 UIKit                          0x18b913360 UIApplicationMain + 208
28 Wize                           0x1001208f4 main (AppDelegate.swift:19)
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x1849205b8 (Missing)
```

Any idea what may be going on? It works fine for half the users.

Comment: Which line is line 363?

Comment: @rmaddy I think it's the last line self.presentViewController, but my code might have changed, will have to crash it again to get the new line number. Will report back.

Comment: Since there is mention of dynamic cast could it be this line: sender as! UIView

Comment: Why are you guessing? Run the app in Xcode and see which line is actually causing the crash. Then update your question with exact relevant code and point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy It actually doesn't crash for me--only for certain users.

Comment: It's hard to help if you can't even point out the correct line. Don't you have your code in source code control or a backup from when you released it? Extract out the copy of the file used to build your release and post that code and point out line 363.

Comment: Yes, it's this line: activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView

Comment: Why is `sender` declared as `AnyObject` instead of `UIButton` or `UIBarButtonItem` or whatever it really is? Then you wouldn't need the `as! UIView` cast at all.

Comment: I couldn't change it to a UIBarButtonItem (compile error), but I changed it to UIButton. Will give this a shot and see if it's fixed on the culprit device. Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check the sender before converting it:

```
    guard let sourceView = sender as? UIView else {
        return
    }
```

...

```
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
```

Answer (score 0):

For this below line

```
 activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView
```

add this line

```
 if let senderSourceView = sender as? UIView {

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = senderSourceView

 }else{
    //Here not getting UIView
 }
```

It's possible App crash because if UIView not get for sourceView.It is work if right as i said.